# Большая буква в диалоге

Tags: орфография

В какой ситуации в диалоге слова автора могут начинаться с большой буквы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Покажу на схемах, думаю, разберетесь))

А: *слова диалога с новой строки*
— П1?
— П2, — а.

А: "П1?" — "П2".

А: "П1?" А: "П2".